# c# and wpf crisis with blank listbox items

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitems

I gave up on my code bugs so I decide to write here. I really hope to get a solution. What I want with the listbox is: when i click the button, it will retrieve data from database then load it into the listbox. It worked fine. But when I add wpf style, it started problem because I want to add image into each item next to text - image (right side) and text (left side). The result in the listbox is blank but actually it seems there is a data list - please look at the picture. I may have done something wrong in my code or wpf. I am not sure what is problem.... I would appreciate if you can have a look at my code. Your given code would be much helpful. Thanks alot!

WPF:

```
    <ListBox Name="lstDinner" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="513,85,608,445" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=styleListBox}"/>
```

WPF STYLE:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="templateListBoxItem">
    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                Margin="0,0,10,0">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}"
                   Stretch="Fill"
                   Height="40"
                   Width="40"></Image>
        </Border>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=About}"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Grid.Row="1"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<Style x:Key="styleListBox" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=templateListBoxItem}"></Setter>
</Style>
```

C#:

```
   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _dinnerExtractor = new DinnerExtractor();
        const int oneDay = 1;

        _databaseDinnerList = new ObservableCollection<FoodInformation>(_dinnerExtractor.GetDinnerDays(oneDay));

        if (_databaseDinnerList != null)
        {
            foreach (var list in _databaseDinnerList)
            {

                lstDinner.Items.Add(new FoodInformation { Dinner = list.Dinner, DinnerImage = list.DinnerImage});
            }

            //lstDinner.ItemsSource = _databaseDinnerList;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: @kmatyaszek is correct in his answer below. For future reference, if you watch the output window when you're running your program, you should see binding errors appearing in this case, which should have been a clue that this is your problem. I always look there first when something doesn't appear correctly in my view! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FoodInformation` class does not contains properties: `Image` and `Name` (you are trying binding to these properties in `DataTemplate`).

From code-behind we can create definition of `FoodInformation` class with properties `Dinner` and `DinnerImage`:

```
class FoodInformation
{
    public string Dinner { get; set; }
    public ImageSource DinnerImage { get; set; }
}
```

So you should binding to properties `Dinner` and `DinnerImage`, not to `Image` and `Name`.

If you change in `DataTemplate` appropriate properties names everything will be ok.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="templateListBoxItem">
    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                Margin="0,0,10,0">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=DinnerImage }"
                   Stretch="Fill"
                   Height="40"
                   Width="40"></Image>
        </Border>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Dinner }"
                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: i use binary images from database and convert it to images. im not using image file path. how to solve this?

Comment: @user1358072 on this question you can find answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418087/how-to-retrieve-images-from-sql-server-database-into-wpf-form-linq-databindi